# Tire size switch out to wider tire , is that possible

Tags: tire

I have a Bacchetta Sparta with 650x 23c tires, can I switch out to a wider tire ? Seems it would be more stable.

Comment: Please check the linked duplicate and all its answers, and try to apply them to your bike.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html Yes this link will give you and idea of the limits .

Comment: It also depends on the brakes and frame/fork clearance. Rim width is only one factor.